# What is this type {x: 1, y: 2} in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript what is this type?

```
a = {x :1 , y: 2};
```

In many js tutorials, I've not seen this just:
  `var a = new a();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is an "[object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals)".

Outside of Javascript it is usually known as an associative array / dictionary.

To declare `a` with the `new` expression (not recommended):

```
var a = new Object();
a.x = 5;
a.y = 6;
```

Comment: but in many js tut, to declare object -> var a = new a();. I don't see anything about this .

Comment: @Snoob: Because `a` is not a type. To declare an object using the `new` expression, you need to use `var a = new Object();`

Answer (score 3):

It is called "Object".
Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

To see what type of variable you have, and what constructor was used to create it, you can run this code:

```
a = {x :5 , y: 6};
alert("TypeOf a = " + typeof(a) + "\nConstructor of a = " + a.constructor);
```

Comment: But in your link : var o = new Object();.

Comment: {} in javascript is a short way to write "new Object", just like "[]" is a short way to write "new Array"

Comment: Read "Creating Objects" here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Creating_objects

Answer (score 1):

That is a javascript `Object` that contains two properties: `x` and `y`.

You can access them like this:

```
alert(a.x + x.y) // should display "11"

a.x = 10 // this sets x to 10

a["x"] = 10 // alternate way to access a property
```